# Exporting vector contour lines from 3D Map view in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, export, contour, 3d-map

Is there a way to export the contours in a 3D map view in QGIS to vectors?

Here is my 3D map view.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok im making a few assumptions here about this setup.

1. Your 3D Map view will be based off of layers/data that exists in a normal 2D view. Lets operate in there.
2. The image you have posted above is a raster image.

On the above assumptions, I would use the `GDAL > Raster Extraction > Contour tool`.

Comment: 1) Yes, this is based on a 2D map—which I can create a print view of and export as a vector PDF to edit in Illustrator.

2) The image above is a screenshot of my "3D map view" in QGIS which is vector based—I want to export that view also as vectors. How do I do that?